# Перенести и обновить данные из одной базы в другую

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, sql

Всем доброе время. Я уже не однократно подымал этот вопрос тут. Наверно я не корректно его задавал. Попробую еще раз описать суть вопроса:

Есть 2-е базы. Одна на MS SQL2012 вторая на Fierbirde 2.5 В базе данных MS SQL2012 я не могу добавить тригер или вложенную процедуру. Т.к. это приводит к тому, что программа которая работает с MS SQL2012 перестает работать, сразу при запуске программы программы выдает сообщение что база не соответствует. Это программа куплена в германии.

Вторая база на Fierbirde 2.5, и моя программа работает именно с этой базой.

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно переносить данные из базы MS SQL2012 в Fierbirde 2.5. ЭТО Я СДЕЛАЛ.

Но не получается сделать следующий этап. НУЖНО ДОПИСЫВАТЬ (ПЕРЕНОСИТЬ) ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ MS SQL2012 НОВЫЕ СТРОКИ В ТАБЛИЦЫ Fierbirde 2.5 БЕЗ ДУБЛИРОВАНИЯ.

ПОДСКАЖИТЕ КАК ЭТО МОЖНО ОСУЩЕСТВИТЬ?

Мне Yura Ivanov подсказал план действий, но я не силен в SQL и не пойму как это осуществить.

1. Выполнить select id from table1 из главной базы
2. Загнать эти idшники в хэш-таблицу
3. Выполнить select id from table2 из второй базы
4. Пробежать по выборке, определить idшники в хэш-таблице
   как только запись с id не обнаружилась перенести ее.

Согласно примера Yura Ivanov.

```
ADZakaz.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM  VKVORGANGSTUB ORDER by VSX_ID';
     ADZakaz.Open;
     ADZakaz.First;
    SQL_Zakaz1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT VSX_ID FROM BASA$KLAES$ZAKAZ_Z ORDER by VSX_ID';

    SQL_Zakaz1.Active := true - нельзя использовать так как такого параметра нет.       

        while not ADZakaz.Eof do
         begin
           while SQL_Zakaz1.ParamByName('VSX_ID').AsInteger < ADZakaz.FieldByName('VSX_ID').AsInteger do - тут выдает ошибку.
                       SQL_Zakaz1.Next;
           if SQL_Zakaz1.ParamByName('VSX_ID').AsInteger > ADZakaz.FieldByName('VSX_ID').AsInteger then
          //
          ADZakaz.Next;

         end;
    end;
```

Comment: уберите 

    SQL_Zakaz1.Prepare; 

prepare нужно выполнять только если вы один и тот же запрос выполняете несколько раз. если запрос выполняется один раз, то prepare вызывается при открытии и так. ну и вызывать prepare после открытия соответственно смысла нет, будет `SQL_Zakaz1.Active = false`

Comment: Для работы с базой Fierbird использую компонент FibPlus - pFibQuery. Для этого компонента параметра Active нет.
  И как открыть эту базу.
 Простые выборки из базы Fierbird я делаю с использованием DataSet.
Может я не правильный компонент использую?

Comment: @kadekin778, Все правильно вы используете, надо просто познакомиться с примерами/документацией. Чтоб выполнить запрос надо вызвать `SQL_Zakaz1.ExecQuery;`

Answer (score 1):

Можно из без хэш-таблицы обойтись, да.

```
mssqlquery.Sql.Text := 'select * from table1 order by id';
mssqlquery.open;
mssqlquery.First;
fbquery.Sql.Text := 'select id from table1 order by id';
fbquery.Open;
fbquery.First;
while not mssqlquery.Eof do
begin
  while fbquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger < mssqlquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger do
    fbquery.Next;
  if fbquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger > mssqlquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger then
    InsertRowToFB(mssqlquery);// здесь идет вставка в FB-базу
  mssqlquery.Next;
end;
```

ЗЫ код возможно с ошибками, воспринимать как псевдокод.

Comment: Спотыкаюсь на этой строке

while fbquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger < mssqlquery.FieldByName('id').AsInteger do

сообщение fbquery нет значений id

в таблице точно есть это поле.

Comment: @kadekin778, может вы не открыли fbquery? `fbquery.open; fbquery.first;`

Comment: @kadekin778, отредактируйте свой вопрос. Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @kadekin778, вам нужно отредактировать свой вопрос, а не добавлять ответ. под вопросом должна быть ссылка [править](http://hashcode.ru/questions/307466/edit/). в окне редактирования вопроса кнопки редактора присутствуют.

Comment: Код можно также положить сюда http://pastebin.com